# MySQL - How to DISREGARD the records less than the CURRENT_DATE with the same FOREIGN KEY?

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin

This is might be a simple problem for some but I badly need help.

Here is my table namely `contribution`:

| id | entityno | oreceipt | oramount | ordate | datestarted | validity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 5 | 8 | 1 | 60 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-02-04 |
| 6 | 9 | 2 | 60 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-02-04 |
| 7 | 8 | 3 | 60 | 2020-12-04 | 2020-12-04 | 2021-01-04 |
| 11 | 8 | 4 | 60 | 2021-02-22 | 2021-03-04 | 2021-03-04 |

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7nh9H.png)

What query can I use to select the records less than the `current_date` using `validity` as the basis?

The **expected output** is the record on the red marker corresponds to `entityno = 9` only. Since `entityno = 9` was expired last 04 February 2021 and `entityno = 8` will expire on 04 March 2021.
[image]

Expected output:

| id | entityno | oreceipt | oramount | ordate | datestarted | validity |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6 | 9 | 2 | 60 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-01-04 | 2021-02-04 |

[Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=c792cabfa62bb0034359229789f40d08)

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Not a single value there that indicates 'SAME ID'. Can you clarify more? And please don't post photos. It's hard for us if we want to attempt to re-create.

Comment: Sorry, to be clear, the term there is 'ENTITYNO' not 'ID'.

Comment: Could you post a visualization of your expected output?

Comment: Please refer to the second picture. The expected output is the record highlighted on red marker. The record with `entityno = 9`

Comment: So `entityno=8` won't be shown at all in the result?

Comment: Yes @FaNo_FN that's correct.

Comment: See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably can do something like this:

```
SELECT A.* FROM contribution A 
JOIN
(SELECT entityno, MAX(validity) mxv 
  FROM contribution 
  GROUP BY entityno) B
ON A.entityno=B.entityno AND A.validity=B.mxv
WHERE validity < CURDATE();
```

Idea is to:

1. Get the `entityno` with their maximum `validity` date, hence `MAX(validity)`.
2. Then make it as a sub-query and `JOIN` with `contribution` table by matching `entityno` and `validity=MAX(validity)`. This suppose to return each `entityno` with their maximum `validity`.
3. Then with that do a `WHERE` condition to get any `entityno` that have `validity` date smaller than `CURDATE()`.

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=3ff915f82079249244af5d3ac3bc59b8)

Comment: Thanks for the answer Sir. Have a good day.

Comment: Glad I could help. You have a good day too!